# How to Get Current Id From One ForLoop (NgFor) to Another

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, ngrx-store

sorry This is my New Question, Previously one question is there am edit this with new one..

This is My New Question 
I have created one image popup with slider , on clicking one image from image gallery , i need to show the particular image in pop up and slider ,
I am using NgFor for Image Gallery and during popup am using another ngFor for slider, i need the clickable image id and show the particular image in the pop up, and am using ngrx-store
this is my code,

```
 <div class="swiper-slide " *ngFor="let picture of pictures; let i = index">
        <div class="zoomImage" >
            <img class="img-fluid GridImage" 
                 (click)="lgModal.show()"
                 src="{{picture.regularUrl}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="pictures.length%2 !=0" class="swiper-slide ">
        <!--<img  class="img-fluid GridImage"-->
        <!--src="../../assets/images/dummy-image.jpg" />-->
        <img class="img-fluid GridImage"
             src="http://dev.rileyblakedesigns.com/media/productimage-
    picture-c120-lightgray-27516.jpg"/>
    </div>
<!--</swiper>-->

<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
     data-a8n="popUp OverLay" id="backgroundPopUp"
     role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right"
            data-a8n="PopUp Close Button" id="popCloseBtn"
            (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

    <carousel [interval]="'false'" [noWrap]="'true'" id="thumbChange" >
        <div style=" " class="closeDiv"
             (click)="lgModal.hide()" >
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

               <div class="modal-content" >
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <slide *ngFor="let picture of pictures; let i = index" >
                        <div >
                            <img class="img-fluid popUpImage" 
                                 src="{{picture.regularUrl}}" >
                            <div class="pull-right imageCount"
                                 ">
                                <h6 class="countPic" >{{i+1}} of {{ 
                          pictures.length}}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </slide>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="PopUp-Thumbnail"  data-a8n="PopUp-Thumbnail"
             style="">
            <span *ngFor="let picture of pictures; let i = index" >
                <img class="img-fluid GridImagePopUp active" 
          id="thumbnailImage"
                src="{{picture.thumbnailUrl}}">
        </span>
        </div>

    </carousel>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to specify how the authentication is implemented on the resource. If it is standard HTTP Authorization, you can inject a proper header using the config parameter of the $http service.

Comment: ya standard HTTP Authentication $http.get

Comment: am struggle to type a script for this . first login the file using url then collect data from json

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "data" try using "params" like this:

```
var App= angular.module('myApp',[]);
App.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope ,$http) {
    $scope.userName ="usern";
    $scope.password ="pass";

    $http({
        method :'GET',
        url:' paste url here',
        params: { username :  $scope.userName , password: $scope.password},

        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
{
        console.log('status',status);

        console.log('data',status);
        console.log('headers',status);
    });
});
```

This is how it should work. see here [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage/)

Comment: sorry its not working.... i can't login that page..

i am using angularjs as front end and drupal as backend.

json data in drupal but i can't access without login. am struggling with login issues

Comment: This example above can only pass data to the backend, you need to figure out how to execute them in the backend. You can not login in this way and get the data. So the problem is with user authentication which is related to sessions, web tokens etc. I recommend using JSON Web Token for authentication then pass Token value with $http request instead of username/password. Then you can get the data from the backend and angular works great with JWT. Here is some information about JWT https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt.

Comment: Actually, I'm not a drupal expert. But I think if you know how to work with JWT then it will be easier to implement it with your drupal application. Here is some info working with drupal JWT https://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=1297 which is using cURL for example. You have to convert cURL actions into your $http request they are pretty similar. Also, a working example with Laravel + angular is here https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps. Hope they can help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is basic HTTP authorization, this should authenticate you.

```
var App= angular.module('myApp',[]);
App.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope ,$http) {
    $scope.userName ="usern";
    $scope.password ="pass";

    $http({
        method :'GET',
        url:' paste url here',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization':'Basic '+btoa($scope.userName+':'+$scope.password)}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
{
        console.log('status',status);

        console.log('data',data);
        console.log('headers',headers);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry its not working.... i can't login that page..

i am using angularjs as front end and drupal as backend.

json data in drupal but i can't access without login. am struggling with login issues

Comment: Then you're not using standard HTTP authentication. You will have to either change Drupal to support it, or make a solution where you fetch a cookie by posting to the login page first, fetch the returned cookies, and send them with the request for fetching the data.